# When to call Parcel.recycle()?

Tags: java, android, parcel, android-binder

I have to work with `IBinder`s and `Parcel`s. I've gone through all of the [IBinder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder), [Binder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder), and [Parcel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel) documentation and could not find anything which talks about when to call `Parcel.recycle` (I also never read anything that said that a `parcel` must be recycled). I've seen examples like the following:

```java
void someMethod(IBinder binder) {
  final int code = // ...
  final Parcel data = Parcel.obtain()
  final Parcel reply = Parcel.obtain()

  try {
    binder.transact(code, data, reply, 0);
  } finally {
    data.recycle();
    reply.recycle();
  }
}
```

But the thing that confuses me is that in every example, I do **NOT** see this:

```java
class MyBinder extends Binder {
  @Override
  public boolean onTransact(int code, Parcel data, Parcel reply, int flags) {

    try {
      // do things...
    } finally {
      data.recycle();
      // calling reply.recycle() doesn't make sense because it has to be sent
      // back to the client
    }

  }
}
```

Does this mean that calling `recycle` will recycle the parcel on both the ends of the connection? Or are the data and reply parcels (in the `onTransact` method) just recycled behind the scenes when `onTransact` method exits.

And if someone does have the answer, where did you find it out from? Is there some sort of secret book or website that documents this? I can't find it anywhere on https://developer.android.com

Ideally what I would like to do is get the data parcel from `onTransact` and pass it into a task inside of a thread pool. But because I don't know when (or if) the parcel gets recycled, I don't know when (or if) I can use the data parcel.

Answer (score 0):

> in every example, I do NOT see this

That is expected. It would be the responsibility of the caller of `onTransact()` to recycle its `Parcel`. After all, `onTransact()` has no idea if the caller intends to reuse that `Parcel` instance.

> Does this mean that calling recycle will recycle the parcel on both the ends of the connection?

AFAIK, no.

> Or are the data and reply parcels (in the onTransact method) just recycled behind the scenes when onTransact method exits.

Yes.

> And if someone does have the answer, where did you find it out from?

I looked at the source code to `Binder`, where [`onTransact()` is being called](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Binder.java;l=1169-1251?q=reply.recycle). The `finally` block recycles the `Parcel` instances.

> Ideally what I would like to do is get the data parcel from onTransact and pass it into a task inside of a thread pool. But because I don't know when (or if) the parcel gets recycled, I don't know when (or if) I can use the data parcel.

Since the `Parcel` is recycled, that is not safe. You will want to grab the data out of that `Parcel` and put it in something else that you put in your thread pool.